# Can I use Crystal Report For Both Visual Studio 2010 and 2017 in a machine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

There are several projects in my company. Most of them were built in Visual Studio 2010. Now we are building a new application in Visual Studio 2017. The problem is that with crystal report.

The projects that were built in Visual Studio 2010 have lots of reports and many clients are using these applications. Now we are using Visual Studio 2017 for the new application for creating reports we need to work with **Crystal Report**.

But when I installed crystal report version for Visual Studio 2017 it updated the previous **Crystal Report** version on my machine. After that when I opened our existing application in Visual Studio 2010 it was throwing an exception about crystal report assembly were not found. Then I uninstalled the updated version of Crystal Report and reinstall the previous one.

But I need to work with Crystal Report in both Visual Studio 2010 and 2017 on my machine. Any suggestions for how I can achieve this?

Comment: You should ask the vendor of Crystal Report. Otherwise use virtual machines for each VS installation and the needed Crystal Report version

Answer (score 0):

if you have an Excel source as a crystal clear report check modifying the version of the file as it can work in both versions but you need to select the excel file version from the Connection manager. It worked for me doing that.